# Pyaudio: How to Playback wav file in separate process(multiprocessing)?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pyaudio

I am writing a program that is supposed to play a wav file as long as the amplitude, detected by a microphone is over a certain level. I want to use(and have succesfully to some extent in the past) pyaudio, because i need to handle 2 streams at the same time. Now the problem arises when

I want to play the wav file in a process separate from the main thread. The following code is just a proof of concept:

```
import pyaudio,wave
import multiprocessing,time

filename='/home/larfan/Documents/PythonProgramming/overtone_horn/soundsamples/ZOOM0065.WAV'
#open soundfile
wf = wave.open(filename, 'rb')


chunk = 1024*4  
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
class output:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stream = p.open(format = p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
                    channels = wf.getnchannels(),
                    rate = wf.getframerate(),
                    output = True)
        # Read data in chunks
        self.origdata = wf.readframes(chunk)
    def actualoutput(self):
        data=self.origdata
        # Play the sound by writing the audio data to the stream
        while data:
            self.stream.write(data)
            data = wf.readframes(chunk)
    def testfuntion(self):
        print('hi')
        

out=output()

t1=multiprocessing.Process(target=out.actualoutput)
t1.start()
time.sleep(2)
out.stream.close()

t1.terminate()


p.terminate()
```

If I run this code I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/larfan/Documents/PythonProgramming/overtone_horn/ultimatetest.py", line 23, in actualoutput
    self.stream.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 586, in write
    exception_on_underflow)
OSError: [Errno -9999] Unanticipated host error
```

When I call out.actualoutput() all by itself if perfectly works and also if I use multiprocessing with run() instead of start() it also works. I can't however use run() because I want the main thread to continue and I want to use the terminate() option as exemplified in the code above. In the real program I obviously want to call terminate() as soon as the amplitude drops under a threshold and not after a fixed amount of seconds.

Has anyone got an idea on how to make this work. Even just a hint towards the solution would be very much appreciated.
greetings

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to play the file separately from the main program, asyncio's `run_in_executor()` might be the best way to go. multiprocessing is preferred when there are multiple threads and you need to start them simultaneously and collect results.

E.g.:

```
import pyaudio
import wave
import sys
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime
def background(f):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        return asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(None, f, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped

@background
def play_audio(audio_file = 'sample.wav', CHUNK = 1024): #define play function however you like!
    print(f'Audio Play starts at {datetime.now()}')
    wf = wave.open(audio_file, 'rb')

    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
                    channels=wf.getnchannels(),
                    rate=wf.getframerate(),
                    output=True)

    data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)

    while len(data)!=0:
        stream.write(data)
        data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)

    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()

    p.terminate()
    print(f'Audio play finishes {datetime.now()}')
```

Now you can run call this function as per you need and it will always run separately to the main program without putting it into wait state:

```
print(f'Main Program Starts at {datetime.now()}')
play_audio('sample.wav', 1024)
print(f'Main program finishes at {datetime.now()}')
```

produces following output:

```
Main Program Starts at 2020-10-24 16:57:30.819964
Audio Play starts at 2020-10-24 16:57:30.819964
Main program finishes at 2020-10-24 16:57:30.820960
Audio play finishes 2020-10-24 16:58:04.684334
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have looked into it, however I don't think this is a suitable solution for me, because I  need an easy way of cancelling/stopping/killing the playback running in the background. Truthfully I haven't got a version with asyncio as you suggested, to work at all in the desired fashion. Still: Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: Ok I found a way, without using any threading/multiprocessing or implementation of asyncio. I now use pygame.mixer.Channel(0).play(pygame.mixer.Sound(filename),-1) to play the wav file in the background. This gives me the option to go on with the program, as it would be with a separate thread/process. Also with pygame you can easily pause /unpause the channel with:pygame.mixer.unpause()/pygame.mixer.pause(). Thank you for your help regardless!